# How to route domain subfolder with dynamic path name?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, web-hosting

I have two project folder, e.g. blog1 and blog2.

> /var/www/html/blog1
>
> /var/www/html/blog2/laravel

I am doing it as sub folder instead of sub domain.

blog1 folder consists of laravel project. Inside blog2 folder, there's is a folder name laravel which consist of laravel project.

this is my htaccess for blog1

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE] 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog1/public/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

Every time access too blog1 is simple, just https://website.com/login

Every time i want to access blog2 project, this is the link looks like https://website.com/blog2/login

htaccess inside blog2

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ / [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

How can i make the link looks like https://website.com/blog2/ or https://website.com/blog2-sg/ or https://website.com/blog2-uk/?

My expected result

```
https://website.com/blog2/ will go to laravel login page
https://website.com/blog2-uk/ will also go to laravel login page
```

They will route to /var/www/html/blog2/laravel

Can i know is this doable and how to achieve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking in to Laravel Routes Subdomain Routing example:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing.
This demonstrates how to use variable/dynamic parts in the URI.

Point all `/blog2-*/` URIs to the Laravel application and let Laravel do further routing. I don't know your exact situation, but maybe the following redirect rule could help you out:

```
RewriteRule ^blog2-(.*)/ http://www.website.com/blog2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried but it returns 404 for me. I am using http://www.website.com/blog2-uk/, it should return me to http://www.website.com/blog2-uk/login, but i get 404.

Comment: Using the rewrite above, website.com/blog-2-uk/ redirects you to website.com/blog2/. You can achieve what you are commenting by routing `/` to `/login` using Laravel Routes or by changing the RewriteRule, based on your specific situation.

Comment: I have RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog1/public/ [L] in my htaccess. and i added RewriteRule ^blog2-(.*)/ http://www.website.com/blog2 [R=301,L] below, not working. It shows error 404.

Comment: I guess it treats it as the route from blog1, therefore unable to reach the blog2 application.